# UPI links not completing payment

Tags: flutter, uri, payment, upi

I am trying to pay by clicking on upi link as follows

```
upi://pay?pa=abc@upi&pn=payeeName&tr=1234&tn=Pay%20to%20payeeName&am=1&mam=1&cu=INR&url=https://example.com/payment/orderId=123456
```

I can successfully open UPI app with pre-filled data but when trying to pay it says risky payment and/or VPA is blocked and thus payment fails. (Note: Account is active and normal payments are processed correctly)

Is there something i am missing?

I am using url_launcher package in my app to launch above url.